# MDX - Counting attributes where no relation exists

Tags: mdx

I have a Dimension (Account) with two attributes - Group and Account. The cube is a pre-built one and has no hierarchy defined on these attributes.

I need to write an MDX query that could provide me with  number of accounts against each group. 
Changing the cube is not an option so I am looking for a purely programmatic solution.

This could be fairly simple in T-SQL but doesn't seem so straightforward with MDX.

Comment: What do you mean with "no relation exists". WHich measures are available?